# jQuery .replaceWith Not Working

Tags: jquery

Google Blogger uses javascript to place a quickedit icon for the admin on widgets or editable areas.

This is the HTML:

```
<a class="quickedit" href="xxxxxx" onclick="return _WidgetManager._PopupConfig(document.getElementById(&quot;BlogArchive1&quot;));" target="configBlogArchive1" title="Edit">
<img alt="" height="18" src="http://img1.blogblog.com/img/icon18_wrench_allbkg.png" width="18">
</a>
```

I'm trying to replace that image with a Font Awesome Icon. Here is the jQuery that I used:

```
$('a.quickedit img').replaceWith('<i class="icon-wrench"></i>');
```

The original image is still there, there are no related errors in the console.log, so why is it not working? BTW, I am using the `$(document).ready` function, and version 1.7.1.

**EDIT:** I also noticed that using this breaks all of my other jQuery scripts on the page. So there may be a conflict.

Here is everything without the script I'm trying to add:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(&quot;.menu-toggle&quot;).click(function (e) {
        $(this).next(&#39;ul&#39;).slideToggle(&quot;fast&quot;);
    });
    $(&quot;#LinkList1 ul li&quot;).click(function (e) {
        $(this).find(&#39;ul&#39;).slideToggle(&quot;fast&quot;);
    });
    $(&quot;body a, .camera_prev, .camera_next, .camera_pag li&quot;).hover(function(){
        link_audio.play();
    },
    function(){
        link_audio.load();
    });
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() &gt; 100) {
            $(&#39;.scrollup&#39;).fadeIn();
        } 
        else {
            $(&#39;.scrollup&#39;).fadeOut();
        }
    }); 
    $(&#39;.scrollup&#39;).click(function(){
        $(&quot;html, body&quot;).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
        return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

**EDIT AGAIN**: No matter what I try, it seems all other scripts break and no longer function with no visual errors or errors in the console.log. View the template/site in question here: http://xarpixels-revitalize-template.blogspot.com/

FYI, only the admin can even see the .quickedit icon.

Comment: Try creating a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) :)

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/93fsu/

Comment: `.replaceWith( newContent )`, says the documentation. New content, not replacement item. Does this mean you need to select the parent, or something? I mean, <img /> doesn't have any content, being a self-closing tag, so maybe it doesn't work because of that...?

Comment: @Ariane, it means to replace the element you select. The OP is using the right thing.

Comment: If you put that code into the console and run it does it work? If so, that means document ready is not when you want to run the code.

Comment: google probably did their replacement last so your code didn't do anything, you can  try the same replacement code in window load. Also I did not find your code in the js anywhere in your link

Comment: ok, I tried window load, but I get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try alternate way. Like this :

```
$('a.quickedit img').after('<i class="icon-wrench"></i>').remove();
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

As i did not understand the requirement fully, but with others understanding, i have fixed the code, please have a look at this

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r3GgM/5/)

change in css and js code

```
$('a.quickedit').append('<i class="icon-wrench"></i>');
```

Mark as correct, if it fixed your problem

Comment: Appending is not what I want to achieve. I want to replace. Anyway, I tried this anyway and it didn't do anything either. The original image is still there, and I don't see the <i> in the source. All other jQuery scripts seem to fail, with no errors in the console.log.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your CSS class. You need it because the tag i is an inline HTML element. Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/r3GgM/

```
    .icon-wrench{
     ...
    display:block;
    width: xxxx;
    height: nnnn;
    }
```

Comment: interesting, but you didn't read the whole post. the orinigal image is still there. <i> is no where in the source.

Comment: I updated my http://jsfiddle.net/r3GgM/7/ and your entire code is fine. Maybe after your render Google is appending the image into the link.